# Raw IPv6 packet handling on linux

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, ipv6, packet

Is there any utility function on the Kernel like the `ipv6_skip_exthdr()` [[1]](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv6/exthdrs_core.c?v=2.6.34#L66) for instance, which doesn't uses `sk_buff` as input to handle `ipv6` packets? I need some basic functionality to handle `IPv6` packets, I know Kernel does this, but I wasn't able to figure the utility functions to do that, functions that I can use on the user-space to handle raw packets that I have (without `sk_buff` structure).

Thanks !

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to achieve? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I just want to manually parse packets from a userspace application, using libipq for instance. I have the raw packet contents only, I just need to structures needed to parse it without pain hehe.

Comment: Oo from userspace! Sorry with your linux-kernel tag I thought you wanted to do this in kernel space. May I ask why are you not using http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/index.html ?

Comment: I would also like to use libnetfilter_queue, but isn't an option right now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RFC 3542 describes an advanced API to parse IPv6 headers:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3542.txt

It also has suggestions which headers and functions to use for specific tasks. Give it a try.